# Path function is not working as expected in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this route on symfony2:

```
flight_admin_news_form:
 pattern:  /news/{action}/{id}
 defaults: { _controller: FlightAdminBundle:News:form,action:create,id:0 }
 requirements:
        action: create|edit
        _method: GET
```

When I use it like this on my base template:

```
<a href="{{ path("flight_admin_news_form", {"action": "create"}) }}">Add new</a>
```

I expect to get an URL like this: /news/create but instead I get this: /news/

When I use it inside a child template it works...

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the typo-edit without any comment leaving my answer useless... next time report back if such a typo was the cause for your problem, please. Otherwise we can't help you. btw. clear your cache after fixing the typo :)

Comment: @nifr the typo is not the cause of my problem. After I fixed the typo I tried to comment on your answer but couldn't, I got a message about the post being frozen or something.

Comment: Was the typo only in the question or in your code, too? Did you clear your cache meanwhile?

Comment: @nifr the typo was only in the question. I just cleared my cache and nothing.

Comment: can you please try `{{ path('flight_admin_news_form', {'action': 'create'}) }}` ? clear your cache afterwards. Additionally double-check that there is no second route named `flight_admin_news_form` in any of your routing files which overwrites the declaration.

Comment: @nifr just tried that. Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony will generate the shortest route possible. Since "create" is your default action, it generates only `/news/`, because it's identical to `/news/create`.